# Why OncreateView called in non stored fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` and two fragments in this activity like `SignupFragment` and `MenuFragment`.First i add `SignupFragment` in `MainActivity`:

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new SignupFragment());
            ft.commit();
```

**Important:** i don't need to store this fragment in backstack

Now from `SignupFragment` i replace `MenuFragment`

```
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MenuFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

**Important:** i need to add this fragment to backstack.For example i have another framgent like `AnotherFragment` and i replace it in `MenuFragment` and add that to backstack too and when user in `AnotherFragment` pressed back button i want to return him to `MenuFragment`

I override `OnBackPressed` in `MainActivity` and also add a listener for `OnBackStackChangeListener`:

```
   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)
            finish();
    }
});
```

**Problem** When i'm in `MenuFragment` and press back button then i go back to `SignupFragment` and`OnCreateView` called for a little moment and then `finish()` called.( when i press back button , `SignupFragmen`'s view shows for a moment and then destroyed )

**Questions**
1- How can i prevent to returning back to `SignupFragment ?`

2- Why `OncreateView` called in `SignupFragment` when back button pressed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.
when i pressed back button, `OnBackPressed` called and also `MenuFragment` is visible yet then `onCreateView` of `SignupFragment` called and then `onBackStackChanged` called , So i check this in `OnBackPressed`:

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG).isVisible()){
finish();
}
```